# Sockets can't find source files in frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Im using the template for express and angular from [this](http://www.thinkster.io/pick/GUIDJbpIie/angularjs-tutorial-learn-to-build-modern-web-apps#item-521e45b3fe0324d46b00005d) tutorial.

Installed socket.io using npm and the files are visible in `node_modules`.
Server starts normaly (I hope) with `info  - socket.io started` visible in the console.

I run it by changing the `server.js` file from the template.

```
var app = express()
    , server = http.createServer(app)
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
```

and passing `io` to the files i'll be using it in like:

`require('./config/routes')(app, passport, auth, io)`

In the frontend (like in the example on sockets.io) website I add it by simply:

`script(type='text/javascript', src='socket.io/socket.io.js')`

but I get

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your code for the way you are initializing web server listener socket. This is not socket listener, but web server one.

In express it is usually:

```
app.listen(3000);
```

But you need to do:

```
server.listen(3000);
```

*Assuming that this is problem taking in account lack of full source code and missing exactly that part in your question code.

Comment: I've added now the `server.listen(3000)` but still nothing. The full source code in the skeleton is available [link](https://github.com/msfrisbie/mean-stripdown) here. I haven't changed anything except adding my services and controllers in angular. You can check how to source for `server.js` looks there

Comment: So as I understand, you've changed `server.js` and included `socket.io`? Have you changed this line: https://github.com/msfrisbie/mean-stripdown/blob/master/server.js#L50 to the one I've mentioned above? Make sure `app.listen` is removed.